# Using different passports for Entry/Exit when passport-officials from both countries sit at the same desk

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports, tourist-visas, passport-stamps

I have dual citizenship - let us say passport P1 and passport P2.
I am living in country C1 on passport P1, but my tourist visa for P1 is about to run out.
My plan is to travel to neighboring country C2 for a few days, and then return to C1 to stay on passport P2. 
In order to accomplish this, I need to do one of the following :

**Option-1**

On the day I leave C1 :

- Exit C1 on passport P1
- Enter C2 on passport P2

On the day I re-enter C1 :

- Exit C2 on passport P2
- Enter C1 on passport P2

**Option-2**

On the day I leave C1 :

- Exit C1 on passport P1
- Enter C2 on passport P1

On the day I re-enter C1 :

- Exit C2 on passport P1
- Enter C1 on passport P2

*Questions*

Either way, on one of the days I have to exit one country on a different passport than I use to enter the other country. I figure that this is in principle possible, but what I am worried about is this - I have heard that at the border of the two countries, the passport-officials for each country both sit at the same desk together. Does this mean that they may insist that I enter one country on the same passport that I use to exit the other? Does anyone have experience with this exact situation? Should I avoid this situation by travelling by plane to a country which does not share a physical border with the one I am in?

I figure that perhaps Option-1 is slightly better, because in that case, the day of the passport-switch does not involve me entering a country for which one of my visas is already used-up.

Thank you for your help!

I am curious about this question in general, but if it is a case-by-case sort of thing, these are the actual details in terms of the passports/countries :

- C1: Argentina
- C2: Uruguay
- P1: US Passport
- P2: Italian Passport

Comment: You realize that being allowed in a country is for a person, not for a passport? It is likely that country C1 does not want you back in for a second spell, (but not all countries see this in the same way.)

Comment: Sounds to me that this question is about how to evade laws on overstaying, which means it should be closed. Unless there is an example of a country which is happy to let people have as many consecutive maximum stays as they have passports?

Comment: @MJeffryes Yes...but every question about the use of multiple citizenships to ease international travel seeks to avoid some aspect of some country's immigration law. Those questions are common here.

Comment: Are there really border posts where the two actually sit side-by-side? They can be close (see French and UK controls are Gare du Nord for Eurostar departures for instance), but countries have a tendency to have their own turf and really separate both.

Comment: These countries are separated by a river. Where do you think that the border officers might sit side by side at the same desk?

Comment: @jcaron I read online that the passport-officials really do sit side-by-side in this case.